# What are the ContinueWith default values

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

What values use `ContinueWith(Action<Task> continuationAction)` for `CancellationToken`, `TaskContinuationOptions` and `TaskScheduler` and where can I find this in the official documentation?

Comment: It's a very good question. It's strange that MS Doc doesn't contain detail description of this method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MSDN does not explicitly state this but usually when you have method overloads, all other parameters are "default". Let's find this method in [.NET source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,e71924f994d1bb54):

```
public Task ContinueWith(Action<Task, Object> continuationAction)
{
    StackCrawlMark stackMark = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;
    return ContinueWith(continuationAction, TaskScheduler.Current, default(CancellationToken), TaskContinuationOptions.None, ref stackMark);
}
```

So default `CancellationToken` (that is `CancellationToken.None`), empty `TaskContinuationOptions` and current `TaskScheduler` are used.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at most of the actual source code for .Net on http://referencesource.microsoft.com/. In your case the exact overload ([`ContinueWith(Action<Task> continuationAction)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,3771)) looks like this:

```
public Task ContinueWith(Action<Task> continuationAction)
{
    StackCrawlMark stackMark = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;
    return ContinueWith(continuationAction, TaskScheduler.Current, default(CancellationToken), TaskContinuationOptions.None, ref stackMark);
}
```

So, for `CancellationToken` it's `default(CancellationToken)` which is equivalent to `CancellationToken.None`.
For `TaskContinuationOptions` it's `TaskContinuationOptions.None`.
For `TaskScheduler` it's `TaskScheduler.Current`